# Java DecimalFormat rounding issue ( consistency problem)

Tags: java, decimalformat, rounding-error

I am seeing some strange behavior in trying to round doubles to 2 decimal places

Below is the code

```
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        
        double f1 = 100.845;
                
        double f2 = 1440.845;
        
        System.out.println( df.format(f1));
        System.out.println( df.format(f2));
```

This outputs

```
100.84
1,440.85
```

I was expecting 100.85 for the first value.

As I was looking into it further, I found the following

```
101.845 --> 100.84
102.845 --> 102.84
103.845 --> 103.84
.
.
255.845 --> 255.84
**256.845 --> 256.85**
257.845 --> 256.85
.
.
```

I am thinking it must have something to do with the precision as the switch from .84 to .85 occurred around 255( 2^8 -1). But, I am not calculating this value( at least not in this sample code).

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is due to the fact that neither of these double values are exactly equal to the decimal representation used in the Java code; they're instead a close floating point value.

The following is one way to print their exact values:

```java
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(100.845));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1440.845));
```

This outputs:

```
100.844999999999998863131622783839702606201171875
1440.845000000000027284841053187847137451171875
```

`100.8449...` rounds down to `100.84`, since it's closest to `100.84`.
`1440.8450...` rounds up to `100.85`, since it's closest to `100.85`.

In neither of these cases does the half-even logic apply, since neither number is exactly halfway between two potential rounding targets.

By contrast, if you use a number format that *can* exactly represent these values (such as `BigDecimal`), you'll see the expected rounding:

```java
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal("100.845");
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal("1440.845");

System.out.println( df.format(d1));
System.out.println( df.format(d2));
```

Output:

```
100.84
1,440.84
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `HALF_EVEN`, it rounds towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant. If they are equidistant, it rounds towards the even neighbor to the left...

In you case, `100.845` the last digit `5` is equidistant so it rounds to the nearest even neighbor to the left `4`.

Here, you are using `double` which, in memory, can be sligtly off with the value. To make sure the numbers that you are rouding are not equidistand, add the precision error which is `+ 1e-6` for your `double`.